# create a record in visual flow

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, flow

In my opportunity I have a button that opens a visual flow. At the end of the flow, I need to create a record of the child object of opportunity. For this, in the button code I have sent the opportunity id as a parameter, like below:

/apex/OpenFlow?oppId={!Opportunity.Id}

Now how can I access this oppId in my flow?

Comment: Found the answer by myself by creating a variable with type as "Input only" and naming it as oppId

Comment: add as an answer and earn some repetuation :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer by myself by creating a variable with type as "Input only" and naming it as oppId –

Comment: Mark your own as correct and earn some reputation. :)